# Two separate "for" loops for vector inside same scope, prints just the first loop

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

This is the demonstrating code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2); 
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(4);
    a.push_back(5);

    int size = a.size();
    cout << "The size of the vector: " << size << "\n";

    for (auto i = 0; i != 6; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }

    //Based on range based for loop
    for (auto j : a) {
        cout << j ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After the run, the first loop prints vector values. Then the second loop skips (Without any condition).

This is pretty strange [May be not ?].

Can someone please explain this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior.

You are accessing `a[5]` in the first loop, which is *out-of-range*.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that accessing `a[5]` causes raising the exception and control flow jumps to the end of a block (i.e. last `}`)

Comment: No, it doesn't raise an exception. Where do you get that idea?

Comment: @sfk92fksdf Undefined Behavior != raising an exception.

Comment: `at()` raises exception, `operator[]` doesn't.

Comment: operator[] is allowed to throw an exception or do sometzhing else. And ideed VS 2017 throws an exeception if compiled as debug.For at the check is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that you trying to access an out-of-bounds element of `std::vector` via its `operator[]`, which performs no bounds check. Under the hood, a `std::vector` is implemented as a contiguous chunk of dynamically allocated memory (also known as the *heap*). The potential number of elements for which memory has been allocated can be queried via `std::vector<>::capacity()` and is larger or equal to the actual number of elements (the `std::vector<>::size()`).

When a adding a new element exceeds the existing capacity, most implementations of `std::vector<>::push_back()` double the capacity (or set it to 1). Thus, with most implementations, your code will have `a.capacity()` of `8`. Therefore, in practice `a[5]` does not result in a memory access outside of the allocated range and simply returns the value found at the allocated memory location. Thus, if I compile and run your code, I get

```
The size of the vector: 5
1
2
3
4
5
32767
12345
```

Thus, `a[5]` returns `32767`, a 'garbage' value, and the second range-based loop runs just fine.

However, the implementation (or `std::vector`) you have used may have another (undefined) behaviour upon your out-of-bounds access attempt.